# Как сделать toolbar с изображением?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, collapsing-toolbar-layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать почти такой же. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Ваше решение есть в стандартном наборе CoordinatorLayout.
Запустите проект https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample